# Hop Box issue Remote Login Fails

Tags: plink

We have a setup whereby we **cannot** login to ServerB **directly** by using putty.

We have to first login to ServerA by providing username and password and it somehow takes us to serverB and prompts for the password for my login id for ServerB. Providing the password again logs me onto ServerB where I have a script test.sh which I need to execute.

I wanted to automate the execution of script test.sh on ServerB from my local windows machine hence I wrote the below command.

```
C:\Program Files\PuTTY>plink -agent user1@ServerA "chmod +x /export/home
/user1/test.sh; sh /export/home/user1/test.sh" -v
```

This command logs me onto ServerA **but** does not take me to ServerB hence test.sh script is not found.

I cannot logon to serverB due to this hopping concept in place.

Kindly help me with some work around.

Note: ServerA and ServerB both are unix servers

Answer (score 0):

Try using the -nc parameter something likeL

```
plink -agent user1@ServerA -nc user@serverB "chmod +x /export/home /user1/test.sh; sh /export/home/user1/test.sh" -v
```